# Order StackExchange API reponse by date and specify minimum # votes

Tags: stackexchange-api

Is there a way that I can specify a minimum score when requesting comments from the StackExchange API while still ordering by the creation date? I'm currently requesting comments ordered by date and then just ignore the comments where `score < x` when processing the response. For now `x = 2`, but this may increase. The bigger `x` gets the more I'd profit from specifying it in the API call, that is: fewer calls to the API would be made – see bottom of this question for percentages.

Of course I've already played arround with [***Try It*** section](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&min=2&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) of the docs. This seems the logical thing to do:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?fromdate=1531180800&todate=1531094400&order=desc&min=2&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow
```

However, to quote the [Complex Queries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max) page of the docs:

> The API provides the sort, min, max, fromdate, and todate parameters
>   on many methods to allow for more complicated queries. **min and max
>   specify the range of a field must fall in (that field being specified
>   by sort) to be returned**, while fromdate and todate always define the
>   range of creation_date. Think these parameters as defining two
>   "windows" in which data must fit to be returned.

The above is also illustrated by the fact that the symbol in front of the *Try It* sections `min` field, changes from something that indicates a calendar (for `creation_date`) to some kind of counter (for `score`) when switching from `sort=creation` to `sort=score`.

This makes zero sense to me, since the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters render a `min` and `max` argument for `creation_date` useless as far as I'm concerned.

As far as I can tell it's impossible to do what I want to do (i.e. request comments with a minimum score ordered by creation date). I'm coming here in the hope that someone will prove me wrong.

### Edit:

I ran some queries: being able to specify 1, 2, or 3 as a minimum score, reduces the number of results by 85, 95 and 98 percentage respectively. On large request the query reduction would be somewhere in that neighbourhood.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible.  Also, the API has documented bugs with dates, min/max's sorting and pagination.